# Delete duplicates where field1 and field2 are the identical

Tags: mysql

I have a table like

```
productId retailerId
1 2
1 2
1 4
1 6
1 8
1 8
2 3
2 6
2 6
```

Now, I need to remove the duplicates. I've figured out how to remove duplicates when one field is the same. But I need to remove the duplicates such as `1 2`, `1 8` and `2 6`, where both fields are identical.

Any help would be very gratefully received.

Comment: If you set the columns up to be secondary keys then they won't be able to be inserted to begin with. Although you'd have to remove the duplicates before that kind of change is allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mysql's multiple-table [`DELETE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html) syntax as follows:

```
delete mytable
from mytable
join mytable t
on t.productId = mytable.productId
and t.retailerId = mytable.retailerId
and t.id < mytable.id
```

See this running on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad858c/1).

Note that I have assumed that you have an id column as well.

#### Edit:

Since there is no `id` column, there simplest approach is to copy the desired data to a temporary table, delete all data, then copy it back, as follows:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptable
SELECT DISTINCT productId, retailerId
FROM mytable;
DELEYE FROM mytable;
INSERT INTO mytable
SELECT *
FROM temptable;
```

Comment: sorry, there is no id field, just the original two

Comment: That is an unusual table then. No problem though - see edit to answer